# how do i install the ros tutorials here http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm just starting out with ROS.
i'm unable to install the ros tutorials in this this link [navigating the file system](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem).

When I type his command :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<kinetic>-ros-tutorials
```

I get this result:

```
bash: kinetic: No such file or directory
```

Please what can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282049/how-do-i-install-the-ros-tutorials-here-http://wiki.ros.org/ros/tutorials/navigatingthefilesystem/) by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you literally running

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<kinetic>-ros-tutorials
```

? If you are, please remove the `<` and the `>`, i.e.,

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials
```

the entire `<distro>` part (including angle brackets) is meant to be replaced by the distribution that you're using.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
oh thanks
so I'm still in the process of setting up my ROS, I am getting an error message when i run this command
*catkin_make*
The above command is at step 4 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)
Then i get this error Message:
*Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed*

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
Were you able to install the `ros_tutorials` package? If so, please click on the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
Can you please create a new question for the error from your comment? It's not related to this issue.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
yh..i've done that